# Increasing spaces in image between written text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, images, image-editing

I have several images similar to the one shown below. Each image is of the same width. What I want to do is to increase the space between the answer posibilities (A-E) for example by 40 pixels (and keeping the width). How can this be done easily for a couple of pictures with for example Adobe Illustrator?

I have extracted the pictures from a PDF (with slice selection tool), perhaps it is easier to do it directly with the pdf instead of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PDF contains lines of actual text, and is not a raster image, then you should be able to open it and edit it in Illustrator.

From the [Adobe Help website](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/importing-pdf-files.html)

> Use the Open command or the Place command with the Link option
>   deselected to edit the contents of a PDF file. Illustrator recognizes
>   the individual components in the PDF artwork and lets you edit each
>   component as a discrete object.

Without knowing exactly how the PDF was created, it might be possible to simply select and move each line of text with the move tool.  I can't tell you exactly without access to the PDF.

Comment: Yes, I can select each line and move it when opening the PDF but the problem is that when I move it by hand the distance between the lines is not constant.

Comment: Is there a possibility to select a line and move it by e.g. 40px down?

Comment: @machinery Switch on Smart Guides, and click and drag it, [look at the dY co-ordinates](https://imgur.com/a/KQTK4) or alternatively put all the lines of text on top of each other, select them all then click on one, then use the [align panel to vertically distribute them](https://imgur.com/a/X2zkS)

Comment: In Y coordinates you can type after the current pixel position your desired increment. Ex: Y: 700px (you type just +40px). The result will be 740px.

Comment: @machinery you can invoke the move tool dialog by right clicking and choose **Transform->Move** you can then type in the offset, which is both precise and repeatable, with transform again (**ctrl+D**)